# I am unable to find static analyzer for Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, xcode

I am unable to find static analyzer for Xcode 6.1, I tried many search but its all saying that we can enable it in the build settings. But I tried in build settings also there is no static analyzer. I referred Some apple docs but they all describe about Xcode version less than 6, Please help, I am newbie in IOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its under the *Product* menu, or `Shift+CMD+B`

[image: Menu]

Answer (score 0):

LongPress mouse click on PLAY button in the upper left corner of Xcode. 
Select ANALYZE.